# How to create gesture driven dynamic resizable view similar to instagram layout app

Tags: swift, animation, image-processing, uistackview

How can I make something like this : https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlNCX30sTfsldAs/giphy.gif

I know there were some open source libs for this but couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: Did you find something? I looking an implementation the same functionality

Comment: Nope. I can swear I saw an open source lib on this but cannot find it. I found a way to do this with UIStackView but it's work in progress. Will update the answer when finished testing

Comment: Me also looking for something like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726417/ios-resize-multiple-views-with-touch-drag-separators/39258704#39258704) , you can find the swift code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258704/3649485).

To summarize, You need a separator view in-between the resizable view which will make the view resize by dragging. The separator view should be slightly liger wider in size so it can catch drags from the border of the resizable views.

You need to modify the code to suite your use case but after that it worked flawlessly for me.